# Marketing Cloud Content Builder Images not scaling properly for mobile

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, mobile, images, design

We are building newsletters to send our students, but the image styling within the template we are using is not functioning properly. To allow for responsiveness, each image is set to Width: 100%; Height: auto; The original images are all different sizes, but uniformly laid out within the template. When I sent a test, the sizing was gone and the images showed up in my Outlook at original size.

To work around this previously, we have scaled the photos outside of MC before uploading.

I tried adding a max-width style tag to the image html which made no difference. I am frustrated by this as the changes to styling may or may not stick after saving them.

To clarify - uploading pre-scaled images works, it just adds a step I would rather avoid.

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your email.  Hard to help without any details.

Comment: Are you using a Delivery Profile that has the default SFMC headers and footers disabled?  They've been known to cause issues with responsive emails in the platform.

Comment: How are you testing?  Are you doing a Send Preview Test Send or a Guided Send to a test audience?  Are you using an email testing tool like Litmus?

Answer (score 1):

This is an Outlook issue, not SFMC. Outlook does not accept 100% on images, so it instead defines the size based off of the original image size and your current DPI settings. ([Ref](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013))

To get around this, the easiest way is to set a defined html width. This can cause issues for flexible/hybrid responsive designs though.  To get around this, you can try doing something like:  `<img src="yourimage.jpg" width="640" style="width: 100%; height: auto" />`

Outlook will ignore the CSS declaration but most others will overwrite html attribute with the CSS.  This is far from perfect, so test via Litmus or email on acid.

Other option is as you described to resize to max size prior to upload.